# Factorial doesn't output an integer

Tags: python

I'm not a very experienced programmer but I just wrote this in Python to try and find `e`, using the definition that `e` is the sum of 1/0! + 1/1! + 1/2! etc...

The problem I'm having is `def factorial` doesn't output an integer. I realize it wouldn't given how it's written but I'm not sure how I can make it. `total` is what I would want outputted as an int from `def factorial`.

```
e = 0

def factorial(m):
    n = m - 1
    total = 1
    if n > 0:
        total = m
    while n > 0:
        total = total * n
        n = n - 1

for w in range(0,100):
    s = factorial(w)
    e = e + ( 1 / s )

print(e)
```

Comment: gotta love this title...

Comment: Use return, lol @Bitwise

Comment: `e` is a real number. You would not want total to be an integer anyway I guess. Integers only represent natural numbers (including negatives).

Comment: total is just a factorial, it absolutely should be int

Comment: Oh sorry... for some reason I thought `1/2!` was supposed to be read as `(1/2)!`. Of course factorials of rational numbers don't make sense. I should go to sleep now...

Comment: @Bitwise I'm sorry but I just couldn't let that title stand. This will at least make it more searchable in the future.

Comment: Technically, factorial can be extended to all reals except negative integers.  Look up the `Gamma function`.  But, that's not what you are really interested in.

Comment: Just for the record, the title was: "Can you fix this?"

Answer (score 6):

```
def factorial(m):
    n = m - 1
    total = 1
    if n > 0:
        total = m
    while n > 0:
        total = total * n
        n = n - 1
    return total
```

**EDIT**: The problem is that, in order to get information from `factorial`, you have to use a return statement. Anything after the `return` is evaluated, and used as the value of `s` in `s = factorial(w)`.

Comment: It would be better if you explained what the problem was (even if it might be obvious for you and me).

Comment: Lo siento. Added an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The code by Feffernoose works. But to improve the performance in your case, you would better use the "yield" statement to build a iterable object.

```
e = 0
def factorial(m):
    assert(m>1)
    current = 0
    total = 1
    while current<=m:
        yield total
        current += 1
        total *= current

for w in factorial(100):
    e = e + ( 1 / w )
print(e)
```

Update: in the solution with "return", you approximately need O(n*n) time for the factorial value computation. But with "yield", you only need O(n).